# swift 4 JSON difficulties

Tags: json, swift4

I have the following JSON data coming back:

```
{"success":true,"symbols":{"AED":"United Arab Emirates Dirham","AFN":"Afghan Afghani","ALL":"Albanian Lek","AMD":"Armenian Dram","ANG":"Netherlands Antillean Guilder","AOA":"Angolan Kwanza","ARS":"Argentine Peso","AUD":"Australian Dollar","AWG":"Aruban Florin","AZN":"Azerbaijani Manat","BAM":"Bosnia-Herzegovina Convertible Mark","BBD":"Barbadian Dollar","BDT":"Bangladeshi Taka","BGN":"Bulgarian Lev","BHD":"Bahraini Dinar","BIF":"Burundian Franc","BMD":"Bermudan Dollar","BND":"Brunei Dollar","BOB":"Bolivian Boliviano","BRL":"Brazilian Real","BSD":"Bahamian Dollar","BTC":"Bitcoin","BTN":"Bhutanese Ngultrum","BWP":"Botswanan Pula","BYN":"New Belarusian Ruble","BYR":"Belarusian Ruble","BZD":"Belize Dollar","CAD":"Canadian Dollar","CDF":"Congolese Franc","CHF":"Swiss Franc","CLF":"Chilean Unit of Account (UF)","CLP":"Chilean Peso","CNY":"Chinese Yuan","COP":"Colombian Peso","CRC":"Costa Rican Col\u00f3n","CUC":"Cuban Convertible Peso","CUP":"Cuban Peso","CVE":"Cape Verdean Escudo","CZK":"Czech Republic Koruna","DJF":"Djiboutian Franc","DKK":"Danish Krone","DOP":"Dominican Peso","DZD":"Algerian Dinar","EGP":"Egyptian Pound","ERN":"Eritrean Nakfa","ETB":"Ethiopian Birr","EUR":"Euro","FJD":"Fijian Dollar","FKP":"Falkland Islands Pound","GBP":"British Pound Sterling","GEL":"Georgian Lari","GGP":"Guernsey Pound","GHS":"Ghanaian Cedi","GIP":"Gibraltar Pound","GMD":"Gambian Dalasi","GNF":"Guinean Franc","GTQ":"Guatemalan Quetzal","GYD":"Guyanaese Dollar","HKD":"Hong Kong Dollar","HNL":"Honduran Lempira","HRK":"Croatian Kuna","HTG":"Haitian Gourde","HUF":"Hungarian Forint","IDR":"Indonesian Rupiah","ILS":"Israeli New Sheqel","IMP":"Manx pound","INR":"Indian Rupee","IQD":"Iraqi Dinar","IRR":"Iranian Rial","ISK":"Icelandic Kr\u00f3na","JEP":"Jersey Pound","JMD":"Jamaican Dollar","JOD":"Jordanian Dinar","JPY":"Japanese Yen","KES":"Kenyan Shilling","KGS":"Kyrgystani Som","KHR":"Cambodian Riel","KMF":"Comorian Franc","KPW":"North Korean Won","KRW":"South Korean Won","KWD":"Kuwaiti Dinar","KYD":"Cayman Islands Dollar","KZT":"Kazakhstani Tenge","LAK":"Laotian Kip","LBP":"Lebanese Pound","LKR":"Sri Lankan Rupee","LRD":"Liberian Dollar","LSL":"Lesotho Loti","LTL":"Lithuanian Litas","LVL":"Latvian Lats","LYD":"Libyan Dinar","MAD":"Moroccan Dirham","MDL":"Moldovan Leu","MGA":"Malagasy Ariary","MKD":"Macedonian Denar","MMK":"Myanma Kyat","MNT":"Mongolian Tugrik","MOP":"Macanese Pataca","MRO":"Mauritanian Ouguiya","MUR":"Mauritian Rupee","MVR":"Maldivian Rufiyaa","MWK":"Malawian Kwacha","MXN":"Mexican Peso","MYR":"Malaysian Ringgit","MZN":"Mozambican Metical","NAD":"Namibian Dollar","NGN":"Nigerian Naira","NIO":"Nicaraguan C\u00f3rdoba","NOK":"Norwegian Krone","NPR":"Nepalese Rupee","NZD":"New Zealand Dollar","OMR":"Omani Rial","PAB":"Panamanian Balboa","PEN":"Peruvian Nuevo Sol","PGK":"Papua New Guinean Kina","PHP":"Philippine Peso","PKR":"Pakistani Rupee","PLN":"Polish Zloty","PYG":"Paraguayan Guarani","QAR":"Qatari Rial","RON":"Romanian Leu","RSD":"Serbian Dinar","RUB":"Russian Ruble","RWF":"Rwandan Franc","SAR":"Saudi Riyal","SBD":"Solomon Islands Dollar","SCR":"Seychellois Rupee","SDG":"Sudanese Pound","SEK":"Swedish Krona","SGD":"Singapore Dollar","SHP":"Saint Helena Pound","SLL":"Sierra Leonean Leone","SOS":"Somali Shilling","SRD":"Surinamese Dollar","STD":"S\u00e3o Tom\u00e9 and Pr\u00edncipe Dobra","SVC":"Salvadoran Col\u00f3n","SYP":"Syrian Pound","SZL":"Swazi Lilangeni","THB":"Thai Baht","TJS":"Tajikistani Somoni","TMT":"Turkmenistani Manat","TND":"Tunisian Dinar","TOP":"Tongan Pa\u02bbanga","TRY":"Turkish Lira","TTD":"Trinidad and Tobago Dollar","TWD":"New Taiwan Dollar","TZS":"Tanzanian Shilling","UAH":"Ukrainian Hryvnia","UGX":"Ugandan Shilling","USD":"United States Dollar","UYU":"Uruguayan Peso","UZS":"Uzbekistan Som","VEF":"Venezuelan Bol\u00edvar Fuerte","VND":"Vietnamese Dong","VUV":"Vanuatu Vatu","WST":"Samoan Tala","XAF":"CFA Franc BEAC","XAG":"Silver (troy ounce)","XAU":"Gold (troy ounce)","XCD":"East Caribbean Dollar","XDR":"Special Drawing Rights","XOF":"CFA Franc BCEAO","XPF":"CFP Franc","YER":"Yemeni Rial","ZAR":"South African Rand","ZMK":"Zambian Kwacha (pre-2013)","ZMW":"Zambian Kwacha","ZWL":"Zimbabwean Dollar"}}
```

and I tried to create the correct structures to decode it but an getting the following error:

> ***JSON Error: keyNotFound(Currency_Finder.ResultArray.(CodingKeys in _584D48DBE69C407B9B6B392A081E66D7).resultCount, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key resultCount (\"resultCount\").", underlyingError: nil))

Perhaps someone could take a quick stab at the struct/class definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is crystal clear: There is no key `resultCount` in the JSON

I recommend to decode the JSON simply into

```
struct Currencies : Decodable {
    let success : Bool
    let symbols : [String:String]
}
```

---

```
do {
   let currencies = try JSONDecoder().decode(Currencies.self, from: data)
   print(currencies)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thank you I was over complicating it with another ResultArray struct.  Appreciate the obvious thing I could not see!